# How to Remove Default Web Browser Option

Tags: macos, vpn, web-browser

I installed Private Internet Access VPN and then uninstalled it with CleanMyMac. As far as I can tell there is no PIA folders or files left on the computer (I could be wrong of course). I noticed that in the default web browser options under system preferences, Private Internet Access is listed as an option. How would I go about removing this? Do I have to edit a .plist file? Where would the available default web browser options be kept in MacOS Serra? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer to this question is on Private Internet Access' own website. [HelpDesk](https://helpdesk.privateinternetaccess.com/hc/en-us/articles/219498367-How-can-I-uninstall-reinstall-your-application-on-MacOS-) Running the command they provide in the terminal fixes the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

Open system preferences and go to general (or search for default web browser).

Set Safari as the default.

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer the question. The question is not how to change the default web browser preference. I was wondering how one actually removes one of the available preferences that was added to the dropdown menu after installing a program, (in this case Private Internet Access) and that did not go away after uninstalling the program.